# Need help with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Current query**

```
SELECT *
FROM employee AS E
INNER JOIN credential AS C ON (C.id = E.credentialId)
LEFT JOIN person AS P ON (C.personId = P.id)
```

I want to modify this query so that it I just SELECT the employees/credentials which have both loginroles 1 and 2 (loginrole.id).

**Relevant tables**

```
loginrole
    id
    name
credential_has_loginrole
    id
    credentialId
    loginroleId
```

Comment: have both login roles, or either one?

Comment: both. I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a subquery, which will return the credential Id's that have both login roles.

```
SELECT E.*, C.*, P.*
FROM employee AS E
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT credentialId
      FROM credential_has_loginrole
      WHERE loginroleId IN (1,2)
      GROUP BY credentialId
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT loginroleId) = 2
    ) g ON E.credentialId = g.credentialId
  INNER JOIN credential AS C ON (C.id = E.credentialId)
  LEFT JOIN person AS P ON (C.personId = P.id)
```

**Update**: As per comments, to find employees with either or:

```
SELECT E.*, C.*, P.*
FROM employee AS E
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT credentialId
      FROM credential_has_loginrole
      WHERE loginroleId IN (1,2)
      GROUP BY credentialId
    ) g ON E.credentialId = g.credentialId
  INNER JOIN credential AS C ON (C.id = E.credentialId)
  LEFT JOIN person AS P ON (C.personId = P.id)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `JOIN` together with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*, C.*, P.*
FROM employee AS E
  INNER JOIN credential AS C ON (C.id = E.credentialId)
  INNER JOIN credential_has_loginrole chr
    ON E.credentialId = chr.credentialId
      AND chr.loginroleId IN (1,2)
  LEFT JOIN person AS P ON (C.personId = P.id)
```

Comment: I am assuming `credential_has_loginrole.loginroleId` maps to `loginrole.id`, Also, if a credential ID can never have multiple records in the `redential_has_loginrole` with the same role, you can change the `COUNT(DISTINCT loginroleId)` to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Both your assumptions are correct. I'm worried about performance, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: How would the query change if I wanted employees wither EITHER role and not necessarily both?

Comment: @arex1337 `LEFT JOIN` the `credential_has_loginrole` table with a `ON E.credentialId = lhr.credentialId AND lhr.loginroleId IN (1,2)
` clause, or remove the `HAVING`

Comment: I'm sorry for being stupid, but could you integrate the full SQL into your original answer? One code block for BOTH and one code block for EITHER? I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Scrum Meister's answer is correct. You can alternatively use 2 join trees:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM employee AS E
    INNER JOIN credential AS c 
        INNER JOIN credential_has_loginrole chl0 ON (c0.id=chl0.credentialId AND chl0.loginroleId=1)
        INNER JOIN credential_has_loginrole chl1 ON (c0.id=chl1.credentialId AND chl1.loginroleId=2)
    ON (c.id = E.credentialId)
```

Comment: I generally prefer JOIN to subqueries, but what if I wanted to grab employees/credentials which have loginroles 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6?

Comment: Yep, you'd need one join per role you wanted to check for. No way that I know of to get around that, it's the downside of this option. @The Scrum Meister's is better if the number of inputs is variable.